# Nested difference of sets in set builder notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I am to check if $A - (A - B) \stackrel{?}{=} B$. By inspection the LHS reduces to $A \cap B$ so it's a subset of RHS. I have a problem expressing it in set builder notation though. I know that $A - B \iff \forall x(x \in A \land x \notin B)$ but how do i write down the nested part?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\forall x\left( x\in A-B \iff (x\in A\land x\notin B) \right)$ ?

Comment: Should it? The LHS is just the standard set notation and the RHS is the set builder equivalent and they are equivalent by definition hence the $\iff$. but maybe I'm wrong? Still, my issue is about the nesting part on the RHS.

Comment: $A-B$ isn't a logical sentence though

Comment: If we unwind it it is : $x \in (A \setminus (A \setminus B)) \text {  iff  } (x \in A \text {  and  } x \notin (A \setminus B)) \text {  iff  }  (x \in A \text {  and  } \lnot (x \in A \text {  and  } x \notin B)$.

Comment: Now apply De Morgan.

Comment: @Jakobian - correct. $A \setminus B$ is a *term*, i.e. a "name", while $\Leftrightarrow$ is a sentential *conncetive* that must be flanked by *formulas* (i.e. sentences).

Comment: Conclusion : $A \setminus (A \setminus B) = A \cap B$.

Comment: Just to wrap it up from Mauro's last step. $x \in A \land \neg(x \in A \wedge x \notin B) \iff x \in A \wedge (x \notin A \lor x \in B) \iff (x \in A \land x \notin A) \lor (x \in A \land x \in B) \iff x \in A \land x \in B$